# Firebase onDisconnect broken with airplane mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

So I'm building presence into my app by setting a flag in firebase called `isOnline` to true when the app becomes active and when I initialize the account. For the most part this works, the user is flagged as offline when I kill the app. But when I go into airplane mode, my disconnect handler is never called and the user still appears online.

After reestablishing the connection, I do an action that writes to firebase, and on this write (could be anything at all), the `isOnline` flag is set to false. I'm a bit confused.

This is how I'm handling going online:

```
- (void)goOnline
{
    Firebase *connectedref = [[[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:kPULFirebaseURL] childByAppendingPath:@".info/connected"];
    [connectedref observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        if ([snapshot.value boolValue])
        {
            Firebase *fire = [[[[[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:kPULFirebaseURL] childByAppendingPath:@"users"] childByAppendingPath:[PULAccount currentUser].uid] childByAppendingPath:@"isOnline"];
            [fire setValue:@(YES)];

            [fire onDisconnectSetValue:@(NO)];
        }
    }];
}
```

I call `goOnline` in my app delegate when the app is launched and when it becomes active. When the app goes into the background, there's still activity being posted to firebase so `isOnline` remains true as expected. Is it incorrect to be setting the disconnect handler again if it is already set (in the case of becoming active)?

When the app is terminated or background activity stops for 10-20 minutes, `isOnline` is set to false, which is correct.

Is this the correct flow to be handling presence? Why am I encountering issues when dealing with poor/no network connection?

Comment: The onDisconnect() runs on the server, not the client. It occurs when the socket is closed, which is really the purview of the OS--for an unclean disconnect, this is usually within about 5-30 seconds. To detect connection status on the client, try the `.info/connected` URL. Read more in [offline capabilities](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html)

Comment: I had the same problem w/ web. If I turn off the wifi on my laptop, it was remaining connected, from what I could tell. Like @Kato says, I just needed to wait a bit longer. It took about a minute.

Comment: Thanks @Kato and @frosty. For what it's worth, I just timed it from an iOS app connected to Firebase. With the iOS app in the foreground, I put the iOS device into airplane mode. It took approximately 120 seconds for the Firebase server to trigger the `onDisconnectSetValue` action.

Comment: For what it's worth, the SDK and backend services have changed drastically since this post back in 2015. A lot of the time for the disconnect to register depends on _how_ it disconnects and which SDK we're talking about (Firestore, RTDB, et al). A clean disconnect is pretty fast. Waiting on the socket to time out will be fairly slow. We should probably recheck these. 120 does seem pretty long.